# user select image and detect colour

Tags: android, image-processing, colors, pixel, color-picker

```
package com.example.hello;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
* This activity displays the gallery image picker.
* It displays the image that was picked.
*
* @author ITCuties
*
*/
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  // Image loading result to pass to startActivityForResult method.
  private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;

  // GUI components
  private Button button;  // The button
  private ImageView image;// ImageView

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

      // Find references to the GUI objects
      button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

      // Set button's onClick listener object.
      button.setOnClickListener(this);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      // Here we need to check if the activity that was triggers was the Image Gallery.
      // If it is the requestCode will match the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS value.
      // If the resultCode is RESULT_OK and there is some data we know that an image was picked.
      if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
          // Let's read picked image data - its URI
          Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
          // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
          String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
          Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

          // Now we need to set the GUI ImageView data with data read from the picked file.
          image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));

          // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
          cursor.close();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      // Create the Intent for Image Gallery.
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

      // Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS to handle back the results when image is picked from the Image Gallery.
      startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
  }
}
```

this code select image from gallery ..

```
package com.example.hello;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ColourPickerActivity extends Activity {

 TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
 ImageView imgSource1, imgSource2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_colourpicker);

       // touchedXY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xy);
       // invertedXY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
       // imgSize = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size);
        colorRGB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
    // imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source1);
     imgSource2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source2);

     //imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
     imgSource2.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);

    }

    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
    = new OnTouchListener(){

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

   float eventX = event.getX();
   float eventY = event.getY();
   float[] eventXY = new float[] {eventX, eventY};

   Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
   ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

   invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
   int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]);
   int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);

//   touchedXY.setText(
//     "touched position: "
//     + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / " 
//     + String.valueOf(eventY));
//   invertedXY.setText(
//     "touched position: "
//     + String.valueOf(x) + " / " 
//     + String.valueOf(y));

   Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgDrawable).getBitmap();

//   imgSize.setText(
//     "drawable size: "
//     + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / " 
//     + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

   //Limit x, y range within bitmap
//   if(x < 0){
//    x = 0;
//   }else if(x > bitmap.getWidth()-1){
//    x = bitmap.getWidth()-1;
//   }
//   
//   if(y < 0){
//    y = 0;
//   }else if(y > bitmap.getHeight()-1){
//    y = bitmap.getHeight()-1;
//   }

   int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

   colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
   colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

   return true;
  }};

}
```

this code tell colour of pixel on touch of image which is in drawable folder .. how can i integrate these two activities .. i want to select image from gallery and apply colour detector on this image which is selected from gallery

Answer (score 0):

Firs you'll need to call the second class from the fist one inside `onActivityResult`, adding the `imagePath` to the Intent:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
      (previous code)

      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ColourPickerActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH", imagePath);
      startActivity(intent)
  }
}
```

Then in your `ColourPickerActivity` you'll need to extract that path and load it into your ImageView:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    (previous code)

    String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_PATH");

    //Load image into the ImageView
    imgSource2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
}
```

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: and how to use this ??
   int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

Comment: @user4440416 Thats automatically done by the `ColourPickerActivity` class when the user touches the image. If you look a bit up, you can see that the bitmap is extracted from the drawable of the image. Can you try this to see if it works? :)

Comment: kindly suggest .. m in trouble

Comment: the code i have mentioned is in working condition but i want to select image from gallery and then apply colourpicker on that image ..

Comment: @user4440416 That's what I answered, yo have to add some extra code to both activities.